# django admin page customization

Tags: python, django

**This is what I did in my models.py folder**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.name
```

**But am getting this as my result in my django admin page**
**And I want to display the products by their name**

```
PRODUCT
    Product object (2)
    Product object (1)
2 products
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `__str__` is a method of your `Product` class and not a function of your models file.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks 
But how do I do that?

Comment: yah I just checked it 
It's now working 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.name
```

> def__Str__(self):
> return self.name

it's return objects.name